# VLC chromecast cast fails on untrusted certificate

Tags: certificate, vlc, chromecast, gnutls

I'm trying to stream video using VLC on Ubuntu to Xiaomi mi box (thru chromecast).
When I'm trying to stream, the chromecast recognizing it stream but then it stuck on black screen with only the title of the video.

I looked in the logs and found:

```
gnutls error: Certificate verification failure: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.
```

I've seen over the internet this is may be related to old gnutls version, or that it's a bug fixed in newer versions of VLC. I'm using pretty new version of gnutls `3.6.5` and I updated VLC to nightly version `4.0.0-dev Otto Chriek`, and still the problem persist.

---

**EDIT**:
I've downgraded back to VLC 3.0.6 and tested it again.
My android box information:
Model: MIBOX3
Android version: 8.0.0
Chromecast version: 1.36.151708

My PC information:
OS: Ubuntu 19.04
VLC: 3.0.6 Vetinari

Video information:
Type: AVI
Video codec: MPEG-4
Audio codec: AC-3

full [logs](https://pastebin.com/7Z2rjLmc)
video [here](https://ufile.io/7py68kq0)

Comment: I've also tried this gist: https://gist.github.com/agronick/30efc1a64a917915b7fdea1dffb892ce

Comment: Try the stable 3.0.6 version. That certificate log is not an error per-se, successful chromecast rendering displays it also

Comment: @mtz Tried, and the problem remains. Do you have any other directions to try?

Comment: Share full logs and config info (OS version, chromecast model, etc) and media info with a stable 3.0.6 build

Comment: @mtz Updated the question. thanks

Comment: Share the file please. Does it work with other files?

Comment: I've added the file. I tried also another file (mkv) which didn't work

Comment: Works fine here, so definitely an issue on your side. Try the 3.0.6 version with another computer and also on another network. Your router may be blocking the chromecast

Comment: The version does nothing : Failed on Linux Mint  with VLC version 3.0.8 >> 3.0.6

Comment: chrome, mkchromecast, even youtube & spotify from phone can do that but vlc  is peace of sht can't ... (still on 22.04 and version 3.0.16 Vetinari =) `sudo apt remove vlc`

Comment: simply open your media using google-chrome and cast it to chromecast device =)